# mvc route query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Im new to mvc and am playing with the albumstore tutorial.  in my index view i have a loop like this.

```
@foreach (var genre in Model) {
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, "Browse", new { genre = genre.Name })</li>       
}
```

which results in the url `http://localhost:59443/store/Browse?genre=Dicso`

in my browse view i have similar code

```
@foreach (var album in Model.Albums) {
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(album.Title, "Details", new { id = album.AlbumId })</li>
}
```

however this produces a url with the structure `http://localhost:59443/store/Details/2`

Can someone tell me why the structures are different using the same code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id is a special case because of the routing setup in global.asax.

In global.asax you will find something akin to this.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Comment: ahhhh ok.  Yes i did see that, but i thought controller, action, id where just placeholders.  Thanks